# optimal time for refreshing db schema or db schema duration yii2

Tags: php, mysql, caching, yii2

What would be the optimal time for refreshing db schema or db schema duration. I am using yii2.

```
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
    ],
```

default it is mentioned as `3600 seconds` on yii2 docs

Comment: There is no such thing as universal optimal cache duration. It depends on many things. If your db schema stays the same all the time you can keep the cache for as long as you wish.

Comment: it changes weekly but I have created a mechanism to update cache with any changes in db. I am looking for factors beside db changes that may impact the system if I keep schemaCacheDuration value high for say 30days.